# Flutter Firebase/Firestore I want to display a name and surname from firestore how can I do this

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display first name and last name from firestore. How can I do this I am new with this firebase stuff so please make it easier to understand here is my code

in my register page where I get users information such as First Name,Last Name,email,age,password
all data except password stores in my firestore

```
else {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text)
      .then((value) async {
    Navigator.pop(context); // Close the loading dialog
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(value.user!.uid)
        .set({
      'First Name': firstNameController.text,
      'last Name': lastNameController.text,
      'email': emailController.text,
      'age': int.parse(ageController.text),
      "uID": value.user!.uid
    });
  });
}

--------
--------
--------

  Future addUserDetails(
      String firstName, String lastName, String email, String age) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
      'First Name': firstName,
      'last Name': lastName,
      'email': lastName,
      'age': age
    });
  }
```

the thing that I wanna do is I want to display the data I got from the register page to this home page's drawer header

```
drawer: Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight + 
                Alignment(-0.7,0),



             //this is where I want to display First Name

               child: Text(
                'Ryan',
                style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(
                    textStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, 
                fontSize:17)),
              ),
            ),
            
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight + 
           Alignment(-0.7,.3),

         //and this is the part where I want to display Last Name

              child: Text(
                'Gosling',
                style: GoogleFonts.lexendDeca(
                    textStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: here is the photo of my firestore]

Comment: There is way more code in your question than should be needed to reproduce the problem. While it's always possible that someone spots the problem and posts an answer, chances of that go up drastically if you take the time to create a [minimal, complete verifiable example from scratch](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (aka as a [minimal repro](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)) (read the links please, they're quite useful).

Comment: Thank you for your response I am new on stackoverflow and I am learning how things are working. I have shorten the code as your suggestion.

Comment: None of your code [reads from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) yet. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should write a query like this to find the document where the username and password match your username and password.

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> userdata = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('username', isEqualTo: username)
        .where('password', isEqualTo: password);

var snapshotData = await userdata.get();
    List docsList = snapshotData.docs;
```

This docList will have the only doc where the username and password match your username and password.

Then you can take the **1st** element of the docList,
that will be your userdata and then you can use the data as you want.

Happy Coding :)